# Start Activity from Object

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

The usual way to start an activity is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there a way to start an Activity from an Object?.. like

```
SecondActivity var = new SecondActivity();
var.start();
```

Something like that..?!

Comment: Nope, you will need a reference to `Context` and use the first `startActivity` method.

Comment: why did you want ti do that ?

Comment: You need a reference of the activity from which you are starting the other one. Anyhow why do you want to do that?

Comment: My second Activity is doing some settings Stuff... and i want my MainActivity to be able to access those... I thought the best way to do so would be via object reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass the **Context to your CustomObject** and start the Activity using it:

```
public class CustomObject {

    Context c;
    // and some other fields here...

    public CustomObject(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void startActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(c, SecondActivity.class);
        c.startActivity(intent);
    }

    // and some other methods here...
}
```

And inside your Activity that creates the Object:

```
CustomObject obj = new CustomObject(this);
obj.startActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have this backwards. It sounds like you should **send** a reference to an object containing your preference data from one from one Activity to another. You can do this using the `setXxxExtra()` methods in the Intent class.

To send data back from the second Activity to the first Activity, you should first start the second Activity using `startActivityForResult()` and then override `onActivityResult()` in your main Activity. [The Android developer pages](http://developer.android.com/index.html) have [a very good example about how to do this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).